# Move between activities with Intents, Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Im trying to build a simple app that consists of two activities. The first activity has 2 `Buttons` and an `EditText` field. When pressing `save&move` the second activity supposed to open and show the text that was entered in the `EditText` field (in the first activity). When pressing `just move` button, the second activity supposed to load (and not do anything). For some reason ***nothing happens*** when both buttons are pressed.

*sorry if the names of the buttons are not very clear. Thanks in advance!

Heres the code of the first activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{

    private Button nextBT;
    private EditText mainEditText;
    private String data;
    private Button nextPref;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        nextBT=(Button)findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
        mainEditText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.dataEditText);
        nextPref=(Button)findViewById(R.id.nextPrefBut);        
    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        int id = v.getId();

        switch(id)
        {
            case R.id.nextButton:
            {
                data=mainEditText.getText().toString();
                if(!(data.equals("")) && (data!=null) )
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Other.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Intent_Data", data);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no data to pass", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            }
            case R.id.nextPrefBut:
            {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Other.class));  
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Heres the code of the second activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Other extends Activity
{
    private TextView textFromMain;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_other);
        textFromMain = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mainText);
        textFromMain.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("Intent_Data"));

    }
}
```

edit:

Thanks for the responses. New problem, the app crashes if `just move` is pressed, any ideas? The first button `save&move` works just fine.

edit #2, the logcat from the crash:

```
03-24 12:50:14.135: I/ActivityManager(289): START u0 {cmp=com.example.c/.Other} from pid 851
03-24 12:50:14.314: D/dalvikvm(289): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 980K, 20% free 8310K/10384K, paused 99ms, total 113ms
03-24 12:50:14.584: D/AndroidRuntime(851): Shutting down VM
03-24 12:50:14.584: W/dalvikvm(851): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
03-24 12:50:14.625: E/AndroidRuntime(851): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-24 12:50:14.625: E/AndroidRuntime(851): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.c/com.example.c.Other}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-24 12:50:14.625: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
03-24 12:50:14.625: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-24 12:50:14.625: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-24 12:50:14.625: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-24 12:50:14.625: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-24 12:50:14.625: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-24 12:50:14.625: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-24 12:50:14.625: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-24 12:50:14.625: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-24 12:50:14.625: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-24 12:50:14.625: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-24 12:50:14.625: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-24 12:50:14.625: E/AndroidRuntime(851): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-24 12:50:14.625: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at com.example.c.Other.onCreate(Other.java:16)
03-24 12:50:14.625: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
03-24 12:50:14.625: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-24 12:50:14.625: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
03-24 12:50:14.625: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  ... 11 more
03-24 12:50:14.664: W/ActivityManager(289):   Force finishing activity com.example.c/.Other
03-24 12:50:14.703: W/ActivityManager(289):   Force finishing activity com.example.c/.MainActivity
03-24 12:50:14.974: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
03-24 12:50:15.216: W/ActivityManager(289): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{4112d850 u0 com.example.c/.Other}
03-24 12:50:15.623: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
03-24 12:50:15.643: W/EGL_emulation(413): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-24 12:50:16.443: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): GL error 0x0505
03-24 12:50:16.643: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): GL error 0x0505
03-24 12:50:16.753: I/Process(851): Sending signal. PID: 851 SIG: 9
03-24 12:50:16.773: I/WindowState(289): WIN DEATH: Window{41134870 u0 com.example.c/com.example.c.MainActivity}
03-24 12:50:16.786: I/ActivityManager(289): Process com.example.c (pid 851) has died.
03-24 12:50:16.943: W/InputMethodManagerService(289): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 851 uid 10052
03-24 12:50:17.156: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): GL error 0x0505
03-24 12:50:17.233: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): GL error 0x0505
03-24 12:50:17.366: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): GL error 0x0505
03-24 12:50:46.890: D/ExchangeService(658): Received deviceId from Email app: null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity, I'll try to summarize what was discussed and concluded:

1) The Initial issue (buttons were non-reactive) was caused because they didn't register any listeners. In order for any widget (Button, textview, etc..) to react in some non-default manner it must register a listener, which will be responsible for that reaction. The solution in this case would simply be to add the following two lines of code at the bottom of `OnCreate`:

```
nextBT.setOnClickListener(this);
nextPref.setOnClickListener(this);
```

2) The second issue (app crashes when user presses the `just move` button) occurs in the `Other` class. We see that in `MainActivity` the following line is executed when a user presses the `save&move` button:

```
intent.putExtra("Intent_Data", data);
```

However, no corresponding action is performed when a user presses the `just move` button. The result is that sometimes the intent will have a value attached to the `Intent_Data` key, and sometimes it wont, depending on which button is pressed. Since no check is performed in `Other`, to see if `Intent_Data` has a value (i.e.`getIntent().getExtras().getString("Intent_Data") != null`), you'll get a NullPointerException every time you press the `just move` button. There are a number of simple solutions to this issue. For example, you could add the mentioned check. The best solution, however, would be to keep the intent consistent and simply rewrite the `onClick` method as follows:

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    String data = mainEditText.getText().toString();
    if(v.getId() == R.id.nextButton && data.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no data to pass", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Other.class);
        intent.putExtra("Intent_Data", data);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Also, Consider using  the function: `getStringExtra("Intent_Data")` instead of using: `getExtras().getString("Intent_Data")`. It does the same thing, but it's shorter and more efficient.

Comment: thanks for the input, will keep the things you've in mind. by the way, i did provide the code for the `other` activity, just bellow the `MainActivity`.

Comment: sorry bout that. I skimmed over the question and missed it. I've edited my response accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't set onClickListener for your buttons.

i.e

Add this in `MainActivity`  onCreate method.

```
 nextBT.setOnClickListener(this);
nextPref.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

For one, you haven't set on click listeners for your buttons. Add:

```
nextBT.setOnClickListener(this);
nextPref.setOnClickListener(this);
```

For two, your switch-case syntax is wrong. case blocks don't need brackets. Try:

```
    switch(id)
    {
        case R.id.nextButton:

            data=mainEditText.getText().toString();
            if(!(data.equals("")) && (data!=null) )
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Other.class);
                intent.putExtra("Intent_Data", data);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no data to pass", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;

        case R.id.nextPrefBut:

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Other.class));  
            break;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborated answer. But doesnt the whole point of making an activity implement the `OnClickListener` class is to write less code and making my code more readable? I mean, my `MainActivity` class implements `OnClickListener` and ive overriden the `OnClick` method to act according to the pressed buttons. Why do i have to add the explicit definition for the listeners?

edit:

Comment: edit:
Now the `Buttons` react, but the app crashes when i press `just move`. What did i miss?

Comment: @AlexTal Have you declared the second activity in your manifest?

Comment: Yes, the first button `save&move` takes the user to the second activity (with the data from the `EditText`) so the manifest is updated.

Comment: @AlexTal What does the Logcat say?

Comment: What is at line 16 of other?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26804/discussion-between-alex-tal-and-raghav-sood)

Answer (score 0):

Source class :

```
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class); 
    myIntent.putExtra("firstName", "Your First Name Here");
    myIntent.putExtra("lastName", "Your Last Name Here");
    startActivity(myIntent)
```

Destination Class (NewActivity class) :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view);    

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    String fName = intent.getStringExtra("firstName");
    String lName = intent.getStringExtra("lastName");

  }
```